# Phantomjs: take screenshot of a page after button is pressed in that page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html

I want to take the screenshot of the webpage after the button in that webpage is pressed. Default view of the webpage is like this [image]. And when I press "start flow" the graph starts flowing from right by sliding to the left, and when "Stop flow" button is pressed the view of the page is like this [image]
and I want to take screenshot of this page. But when i run phantomjs after pressing "Stop flow" button(view of the page when I am running pjhantomjs is the second image) it is taking the defualt view of the webpage. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is "pjhantomjs" supposed to be? Also, if you're having a problem with your code then you should show the code.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.